# How to change image after one second automatically in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I have an image called "img1" and I want it to be that when I click on that image, it changes to another image called "img2" and after a second it changes back to the image "img1" automatically

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView.findViewById(R.id.img1);}

        public void start(View view){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Handler with a delay of 1 sec for the first change, and a handler for 2 seconds for the rollback

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView.findViewById(R.id.img1);}
    }
    

    public void start(View view){
        
        new Handler(getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
        }, 1000); // 1 second
        
        new Handler(getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
        }, 2000); // 2 seconds
        
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `view` in the `public void start(View view){` its throwing an error?!

Comment: @Learn2Code It's a code rearrangement; fixed it now.. the  `view` here is the XML  view that references the `start()` method it its `android:onClick` attribute. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.img1);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

This way you are using:

- `setOnClickListener()` on imageView which will be called when image is clicked
- `setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name)` to set new image on your ImageView
- `new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask())` to delay your new command, in this case to delay setting image back to first one
- `1000` is 1 second in milliseconds, if you want 5 seconds then just write 5000